# ExecutorService throws RejectedExecutionException if only initialized with declaration

Tags: multithreading, exception, scheduledexecutorservice

i got some code and if I only use the declaration with initialization as in

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

this will throw me a `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException` on

```
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

but if I initialize again before as with

```
executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

everything runs normal. Why is that? All examples I found do not execute the SingleThreadExecutor every time before scheduling. I thought it's just to set the pool size. And it should be working being intialized during declaration?! I'm confused :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `executor` will throw RejectedExecutionException if it has been shut down when you try to submit a new job for it to run. Your `executor` variable is declared `static`, which means all instances of the class will share the same variable. Is it possible that one instance of your class is shutting down the executor, and then another instance of the class is trying to schedule a new job?

Comment: the code above is pretty much it, i havent even put the shutdown into it, i was just testing the basic behaviour :p but i do initialize the same variable with the same call of Executors... and it only works right before i start to schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. Avoid declaring anything static that isn't final.
2. It was probably `shutdown` at some point.

Comment: in this script there is no shutdown, the task should run infinitely until the app is shutdown :/

Comment: I guess unless we see more code it's impossible to tell really.  The full stacktrace would help as well

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, it was a shutdown -.- i expected isTerminated to be true when no task was yet run -.- thanks for wasting your time for me :p